# mx custom component not working in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, flexbuilder

I want to create flex application by which i can verify user age i have use following code can u tell me why i cant see mx component "dialogtitle","dialogcontent""dialogbutton"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mx:VBox creationComplete="{initComponent();}" height="219" width="560" xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" xmlns:components="components.*" xmlns:local="*">
<mx:Script><![CDATA[
    import com.people.classes.*;
    import com.people.interfaces.*;
    import com.people.utils.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.utils.*;
    import mx.binding.*;
    import mx.containers.*;
    import mx.controls.*;
    import mx.core.*;
    import mx.events.*;
    import mx.styles.*;
    import components.DialogTitle.*;
    import components.DialogContent.*;
    private var birth_str:String;
    private var _controller:IControlManager;
    private var testDate:Date;
    private var i:int;
    private var ageErrorTimer:int = 0;

    public function _AgeVerify_Spacer1_c() : Spacer
    {
        var _loc_1:* = new Spacer();
        _loc_1.height = 14;
        if (!_loc_1.document)
        {
            _loc_1.document = this;
        }
        return _loc_1;
    }// end function


    public function _AgeVerify_HBox1_c() : HBox
    {
        var _loc_1:* = new HBox();
        _loc_1.percentWidth = 100;
        _loc_1.setStyle("horizontalAlign", "center");
        if (!_loc_1.document)
        {
            _loc_1.document = this;
        }
        _loc_1.addChild(_AgeVerify_VBox2_c());
        _loc_1.addChild(_AgeVerify_VBox3_c());
        _loc_1.addChild(_AgeVerify_VBox4_c());
        return _loc_1;
    }// end function


    public function _AgeVerify_Label4_c() : Label
    {
        var _loc_1:* = new Label();
        _loc_1.text = "Year";
        if (!_loc_1.document)
        {
            _loc_1.document = this;
        }
        return _loc_1;
    }// end function


    public function _AgeVerify_Label6_i() : Label
    {
        var _loc_1:* = new Label();
        ageError = _loc_1;
        _loc_1.visible = false;
        _loc_1.text = "You have supplied an incorrect date. Please try again.";
        _loc_1.setStyle("paddingLeft", 19);
        _loc_1.setStyle("fontSize", 12);
        _loc_1.setStyle("color", 16711680);
        _loc_1.id = "ageError";
        if (!_loc_1.document)
        {
            _loc_1.document = this;
        }
        return _loc_1;
    }// end function


    public function _AgeVerify_VBox3_c() : VBox
    {
        var _loc_1:* = new VBox();
        _loc_1.setStyle("horizontalAlign", "center");
        _loc_1.setStyle("verticalGap", 1);
        if (!_loc_1.document)
        {
            _loc_1.document = this;
        }
        _loc_1.addChild(_AgeVerify_Label3_c());
        _loc_1.addChild(_AgeVerify_ComboBox2_i());
        return _loc_1;
    }// end function


    public function _AgeVerify_Label2_c() : Label
    {
        var _loc_1:* = new Label();
        _loc_1.text = "Month";
        if (!_loc_1.document)
        {
            _loc_1.document = this;
        }
        return _loc_1;
    }// end function


    public function _AgeVerify_ComboBox1_i() : ComboBox
    {
        var _loc_1:* = new ComboBox();
        months = _loc_1;
        _loc_1.width = 60;
        _loc_1.setStyle("fontSize", 11);
        _loc_1.id = "months";
        BindingManager.executeBindings(this, "months", months);
        if (!_loc_1.document)
        {
            _loc_1.document = this;
        }
        return _loc_1;
    }// end function


    public function _AgeVerify_ComboBox3_i() : ComboBox
    {
        var _loc_1:* = new ComboBox();
        years = _loc_1;
        _loc_1.width = 100;
        _loc_1.setStyle("fontSize", 11);
        _loc_1.id = "years";
        BindingManager.executeBindings(this, "years", years);
        if (!_loc_1.document)
        {
            _loc_1.document = this;
        }
        return _loc_1;
    }// end function


    public function _AgeVerify_Spacer2_c() : Spacer
    {
        var _loc_1:* = new Spacer();
        _loc_1.height = 13;
        if (!_loc_1.document)
        {
            _loc_1.document = this;
        }
        return _loc_1;
    }// end function


    public function _AgeVerify_Label3_c() : Label
    {
        var _loc_1:* = new Label();
        _loc_1.text = "Day";
        if (!_loc_1.document)
        {
            _loc_1.document = this;
        }
        return _loc_1;
    }// end function


    public function initComponent() : void
    {
        dialogButtons.addEventListener("onOK", onOK);
        var _loc_1:* = new Date();
        i = 0;
        while (i < 31)
        {

            days_arr.push((i + 1));
            var _loc_3:* = i + 1;
            i = _loc_3;
        }
        i = 0;
        while (i < 12)
        {

            months_arr.push((i + 1));
            var _loc_3:* = i + 1;
            i = _loc_3;
        }
        i = _loc_1.getFullYear();
        while (i > 1899)
        {

            years_arr.push(i);
            var _loc_3:* = i - 1;
            i = _loc_3;
        }
        days.selectedIndex = 0;
        months.selectedIndex = 0;
        years.selectedIndex = 0;
        return;
    }// end function


    public function _AgeVerify_Label5_i() : Label
    {
        var _loc_1:* = new Label();
        underAge = _loc_1;
        _loc_1.visible = false;
        _loc_1.setStyle("paddingLeft", 19);
        _loc_1.setStyle("fontSize", 12);
        _loc_1.setStyle("color", 16711680);
        _loc_1.id = "underAge";
        BindingManager.executeBindings(this, "underAge", underAge);
        if (!_loc_1.document)
        {
            _loc_1.document = this;
        }
        return _loc_1;
    }// end function


    public function _AgeVerify_Label1_i() : Label
    {
        var _loc_1:* = new Label();
        _AgeVerify_Label1 = _loc_1;
        _loc_1.setStyle("fontSize", 13);
        _loc_1.setStyle("fontWeight", "bold");
        _loc_1.setStyle("color", 7105644);
        _loc_1.id = "_AgeVerify_Label1";
        BindingManager.executeBindings(this, "_AgeVerify_Label1", _AgeVerify_Label1);
        if (!_loc_1.document)
        {
            _loc_1.document = this;
        }
        return _loc_1;
    }// end function


    public function _AgeVerify_Canvas1_c() : Canvas
    {
        var _loc_1:* = new Canvas();
        if (!_loc_1.document)
        {
            _loc_1.document = this;
        }
        _loc_1.addChild(_AgeVerify_Label5_i());
        _loc_1.addChild(_AgeVerify_Label6_i());
        return _loc_1;
    }// end function


    public function _AgeVerify_VBox2_c() : VBox
    {
        var _loc_1:* = new VBox();
        _loc_1.setStyle("horizontalAlign", "center");
        _loc_1.setStyle("verticalGap", 1);
        if (!_loc_1.document)
        {
            _loc_1.document = this;
        }
        _loc_1.addChild(_AgeVerify_Label2_c());
        _loc_1.addChild(_AgeVerify_ComboBox1_i());
        return _loc_1;
    }// end function


    public function _AgeVerify_VBox4_c() : VBox
    {
        var _loc_1:* = new VBox();
        _loc_1.setStyle("horizontalAlign", "center");
        _loc_1.setStyle("verticalGap", 1);
        if (!_loc_1.document)
        {
            _loc_1.document = this;
        }
        _loc_1.addChild(_AgeVerify_Label4_c());
        _loc_1.addChild(_AgeVerify_ComboBox3_i());
        return _loc_1;
    }// end function


    public function _AgeVerify_ComboBox2_i() : ComboBox
    {
        var _loc_1:* = new ComboBox();
        days = _loc_1;
        _loc_1.width = 60;
        _loc_1.setStyle("fontSize", 11);
        _loc_1.id = "days";
        BindingManager.executeBindings(this, "days", days);
        if (!_loc_1.document)
        {
            _loc_1.document = this;
        }
        return _loc_1;
    }// end function


    public function onOK(event:Event) : void
    {
        var event:* = event;
        testDate = new Date(years.selectedItem, (parseInt(months.selectedItem.toString()) - 1), days.selectedItem);
        if (testDate.getFullYear() == years.selectedItem && testDate.getMonth() == (parseInt(months.selectedItem.toString()) - 1) && testDate.getDate() == days.selectedItem)
        {
            birth_str = months.selectedItem + "/" + days.selectedItem + "/" + years.selectedItem;
            if (Formatters.getYearsOld(birth_str) < 13)
            {
                ageError.visible = false;
                underAge.visible = true;
                if (ageErrorTimer > 0)
                {
                    clearTimeout(ageErrorTimer);
                }
                ageErrorTimer = setTimeout(function () : void
        {
            ageError.visible = false;
            underAge.visible = false;
            return;
        }// end function
        , 6000);
            }
            else
            {
                _controller.updateAge(birth_str);
                visible = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            underAge.visible = false;
            ageError.visible = true;
            if (ageErrorTimer > 0)
            {
                clearTimeout(ageErrorTimer);
            }
            ageErrorTimer = setTimeout(function () : void
        {
            ageError.visible = false;
            underAge.visible = false;
            return;
        }// end function
        , 6000);
        }
        return;
    }// end function

]]></mx:Script>
<mx:DialogTitle  title="Age Verification Needed" width="172" height="45"/>
<mx:DialogContent children="[_AgeVerify_Label1_i(), _AgeVerify_Spacer1_c(), _AgeVerify_HBox1_c(), _AgeVerify_Spacer2_c(), _AgeVerify_Canvas1_c()]"/>
<mx:DialogButtons id="dialogButtons" okCaption="CONTINUE"/>
```

Comment: `var _loc_1:* = new ComboBox();` - this looks like some decompiled code.

Comment: Agreed alxx, decompiled code. Stealing is bad, mmmkay?

Answer (score 1):

I think its because of your import statements. You only use .* if your importing a package (a folder), whereas these are classes, so just use the following:

```
import components.DialogTitle;
```

Comment: i didn't check whether this is the problem, but well spotted =D>!

Comment: i have changed import components.DialogTitle.*; to import components.DialogTitle;  but still i cant see component,  what may be problem Thanks in advance